# I am getting error 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body In 0.options.0.name: Command name is invalid discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, command

I'm making a bot in discord using slash commands and when compiling it gives an error.Considering that I am writing a response to the "function" command, it gives an error

**Error Code:**

```
    Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-1' coro=<SlashCommand.sync_all_commands() done, defined at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord_slash\client.py:416> exception=HTTPException('400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body\nIn 0.options.0.name: Command name is invalid')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord_slash\client.py", line 492, in sync_all_commands
    raise ex
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord_slash\client.py", line 472, in sync_all_commands
    existing_cmds = await self.req.put_slash_commands(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 357, in request
    raise HTTPException(response, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In 0.options.0.name: Command name is invalid
```

**My Code**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_slash import SlashCommand, SlashContext
from discord_slash.utils.manage_commands import create_choice, create_option
import config
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
slash = SlashCommand(client, sync_commands=True)
token = "my token"

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Запустился :) //by YASHER')


@slash.slash(name = 'invite', description = '[Отчет о принятии] Принятие человека в семью', options = [{
    "name": "Пользователь",
    "description": "Тег человека которого вы приняли", 
    "type": 6, 
    "required": True,
},
{
    "name": "причина", 
    "description": "причина", 
    "type": 3, 
    "requied": True,
}], guild_ids = [824998118595887165])
async def invite(ctx, Пользователь: discord.Member = None):
    await ctx.send(f"П, {Пользователь}!")


client.run(token)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nextcord Slash Command | nextcord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71367526/nextcord-slash-command-nextcord-errors-httpexception-400-bad-request-error-c)