# "Task exception was never retrieved" error In discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am a beginner in python and am trying to make a bot in discord.py that has a command that has whoever runs the command explain how to use something. But I get an error that says "Task exception was never retrieved." Included is the full error, which I don't understand.
The code: (things like my name or the token were replaced)

```
import discord
import os
from discord import ext
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import guild
from discord.ext.commands.core import dm_only
from discord_slash import SlashCommand, SlashContext
from discord_slash.model import OptionData
from discord_slash.utils.manage_commands import create_choice, create_option
import time

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='d!')
slash = SlashCommand(client, sync_commands=True)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Ready')

@slash.slash(
    name='HowUse',
    description='Tell people how to use thing.',
    guild_ids=[removed],
    options=[
        create_option(
            name='What',
            description='What we are using.',
            required=True,
            option_type=3 
            ),
        create_option(
            name='How',
            description='How to use it',
            required=True,
            option_type=3 
            )
        ]
)
async def _hello(ctx:SlashContext, What:str, How:str):
    await ctx.send('How to use {}:'.format(What))
    time.sleep(0.5)
    ('{}'.format(How))
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game('HAIL THE BEANS'))
    print('Connected to bot: {}'.format(client.user.name))
    print('Bot ID: {}'.format(client.user.id))

client.run(token removed)
```

Full error:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-1' coro=<SlashCommand.sync_all_commands() done, defined at C:\Users\removed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord_slash\client.py:416> exception=HTTPException('400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body\nIn 0.options.0.name: Command name is invalid\nIn 0.options.1.name: Command name is invalid')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\removed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord_slash\client.py", line 492, in sync_all_commands
    raise ex
  File "C:\Users\removed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord_slash\client.py", line 472, in sync_all_commands
    existing_cmds = await self.req.put_slash_commands(
  File "C:\Users\removed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 254, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In 0.options.0.name: Command name is invalid
In 0.options.1.name: Command name is invalid
```

How do I fix this? Do I have to import something else or am I just doing the code all wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nextcord Slash Command | nextcord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71367526/nextcord-slash-command-nextcord-errors-httpexception-400-bad-request-error-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
   print('Ready')

@slash.slash(
    name='howuse',
    description='Tell people how to use thing.',
    guild_ids=[removed],
    options=[
        create_option(
            name='What',
            description='What we are using.',
            required=True,
            option_type=3 
            ),
        create_option(
            name='How',
            description='How to use it',
            required=True,
            option_type=3 
            )
        ]
)
async def _hello(ctx:SlashContext, What:str, How:str):
    await ctx.send('How to use {}:'.format(What))
    time.sleep(0.5)
    ('{}'.format(How))
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game('HAIL THE BEANS'))
    print('Connected to bot: {}'.format(client.user.name))
    print('Bot ID: {}'.format(client.user.id))

client.run(token removed)
```

I think that this will help
it was giving the error that your command name "HowUse" contains invalid characters this means the capital "H" and capital "U" are not allowed in a server name so try using "howuse" instead of "HowUse"

if this works please mark this as correct

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).