# "In options.0.options.1.name: Command name is invalid" But yet nothing is indicating that something is actually wrong

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

The problem I'm currently facing is dealing with command names in nextcord. (Or so it seems)
The error code shows as following:

```
Ignoring exception in on_guild_available
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\nextcord\client.py", line 497, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\nextcord\client.py", line 2567, in on_guild_available
    await self.sync_application_commands(
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\nextcord\client.py", line 2350, in sync_application_commands       
    await self._connection.sync_application_commands(
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\nextcord\state.py", line 802, in sync_application_commands
    await self.register_new_application_commands(data=data, guild_id=guild_id)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\nextcord\state.py", line 1003, in register_new_application_commands
    await self.register_application_command(app_cmd, guild_id)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\nextcord\state.py", line 1038, in register_application_command     
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\nextcord\state.py", line 1030, in register_application_command
    raw_response = await self.http.upsert_guild_command(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\nextcord\http.py", line 399, in request
    raise HTTPException(response, data)
nextcord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In options.0.options.1.name: Command name is invalid
```

This error usually happens when you incorrectly put a bad character in the `^[\w-]{1,32}$` regex (Please note that I do not know what regex is or how to correctly read it so I'm just going off of what someone said in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71367526/nextcord-slash-command-nextcord-errors-httpexception-400-bad-request-error-c)). So everything should work.

Code that flags the issue:

```
# modlink (link/unlink/purgeall)
@client.slash_command(guild_ids=serverids,description="Link/Unlink mods ids from the reports section. (Manager Only)")
async def mod(interaction: Interaction):
    pass
@mod.subcommand(description="Links/Adds their mod in-game id's to their discord UserID. (Manager Only)")
async def add(interaction: Interaction, target: nextcord.User, ingameID: str):
    if check_manager(interaction.user.id) == True:
        print("test")
    else:
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"{interaction.user.mention}",embed=prefabembeds.NoManagerPerms)
        print(f"~$- log: (failed) modlink add (target: [{target}, {target.id}], ingameID: {ingameID}), user: [{interaction.user.id}, {interaction.user}]")
```

Help would be appreciated. (Even if I missed the tiniest spelling mistake)

I've tried renaming the command through the argument inside of "@client.slash_command()" and "mod.subcommand()", and also just renaming it by the function "async def mod(..." and "async def add(..."

Comment: Where do you see that error?  What triggers it?  Nothing in here shows any "options", so it's hard to believe the error is in this code.

Comment: @TimRoberts i've updated the error to show the entire traceback. But I know this is the code that has to trigger it because commenting it out will make the error disappear.

Comment: So, you have tried changing `async def mod` to, say, `async def mmm`, and then `@mod.subcommand` to `@mmm.subcommand`, and `async def add` to `async def aaa`, just to try to pick non-conflicting names?

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes the same error is still occuring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Command arguments need to be lowercase as well.**

At this point in the code:

```
async def add(interaction: Interaction, target: nextcord.User, ingameID: str):
                                                               ^^^^^^^^
```

The command argument name has to also follow the regex pattern `^[\w-]{1,32}$`, not just the command name typed by the user.

Comment: While both of those things could be true, they aren't related to each other. That regex **doesn't actually enforce lowercase**.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel again I can't read or understand regex. My fault.